# How to write a jQuery function that can be called on its own (no element)

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I'm looking to write a function that mimics the ajax calls from the jQuery library. I do a lot of ajax calls on my current project, and I always end up writing the same blocks of code over and over to address errors and such - I'd like to write a function that can get the error data (or success message, if any) and return it, preferably in a JSON object.

That's not the part I'm worried about, what I really need to do is get the function to work without an element
So, instead of

```
$("#element").transfer("page.php", "post", {'key': "value", 'other' : "data"});
```

I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
$.transfer("page.php", "post", {'key': "value", 'other' : "data"});
```

...Sort of like the `$.post()` and a few other functions (ajax, get, getJSON) from jQuery.

I've tried every which way of writing the function/plugin, but without any success. Anybody know if it's even possible? [or if there's a better way to do it]

Comment: why can't you just use `$.ajax(url, { type: 'post', data: {'key': "value", 'other' : "data"});`? All of those functions are already aliases of `$.ajax`...

Comment: notwithstanding the correct answers, I'd advise against wrapping AJAX in the way you've described.  You can't `return` an object unless your calls are all synchronous (which is generally a bad idea), nor could you then extend it to use deferred objects.

Comment: All I'm looking to do is get a JSON object back from a POST - in the same format each time, without having to write the same lines of code to process it each time. I guess I'm looking for something to work with the returned value more than anything, but my head tried to encapsulate the entire thing, haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define it as any other function

```
$.transfer = function(page, post, values) {
   //function body...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ...but zzzzBov beat you to it :P

Comment: @JoshToth: Hmm, if you hover over time, you'll see that I have posted this 5 seconds before zzzBov :)

Comment: n00b fail. I switched it to you :)

Answer (score 9):

You just set the function on the jQuery object, and it becomes available.

```
(function ($) {
  $.transfer = function () {
    //your custom logic here
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I tried it again, and now it works. Go figure. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define this function on the jquery obj. Just define a new function.

```
function transfer() {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it kept giving me bizarre errors that I wasn't expecting, so I gave up on that one.